# Show tick image when item is selected in WPF Listbox

Tags: wpf, image, listbox

I have this simple ListBox which displays a list of images horizontal en vertical.
I have also added a tick image on every image. Now I would like to enable this tick image only when the item is selected in the Listbox.

How can I achieve this?

ListBox XAML:

```
    <ListBox x:Name="PhotoCollection"
         Grid.Row="2"
         Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
         ItemsSource="{Binding PhotoCollection, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
         ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
         SelectionMode="Multiple">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <Border BorderBrush="White"
                BorderThickness="2"
                Margin="5"
                Background="LightGray">
          <Grid>
          <Image Source="{Binding}"
                 Stretch="Uniform"
                 Width="50"
                 Height="50"
                 Margin="5" />
            <Image Source="{StaticResource Check_24}"
                   Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource VisibleConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}, AncestorLevel=1},Path=IsSelected}"
                   Stretch="Uniform"
                   Width="20"
                   Height="20"
                   Margin="5" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                   VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
          </Grid>
        </Border>
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True"
                 Orientation="Horizontal" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

**EDIT:** This line does the trick

```
Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource VisibleConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}, AncestorLevel=1},Path=IsSelected}"
```

[image: Tickmark on all images but should only be active on the selected images.]

Comment: @ Joulukuusi. I understand that I need to bind the thick image's visibility to the IsSelected state of the Listbox item, but I can't see how to do it in my XAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I need to bind visibility of items to boolean values, I've been using a converter class:

```
public class BoolToVisibleOrHidden : IValueConverter {
        public BoolToVisibleOrHidden() { }
        public bool Collapse { get; set; }
        public bool Reverse { get; set; }
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
            bool bValue = (bool)value;
            if (bValue != Reverse) {
                return Visibility.Visible;
            } else {
                if (Collapse)
                    return Visibility.Collapsed;
                else
                    return Visibility.Hidden;
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
            Visibility visibility = (Visibility)value;
            if (visibility == Visibility.Visible)
                return !Reverse;
            else
                return Reverse;
        }
    }
```

After grabbing an instance of it in XAML like so :

```
<local:BoolToVisibleOrHidden x:Key="BoolToVisConverter" Collapse="True" />
```

I can bind visibility of items like this:

```
Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}, Path=DataContext.PATHTOBOOLEAN}"
```

Comment: Same here, from where should I get the value 'DataContext.PATHTOBOOLEAN'? How can I reference it to the state of the ListboxItem?

Comment: @PitAttack76 Try DataContext.IsSelected .  This may return the list item's selected property.  Watch the output window for a databinding error message to determine if this is correct or not.

Comment: Now I've created the converter and chenged the Visibility binding to: Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource VisibleConverter}, Path=DataContext.IsSelected}" but no luck. I see no errors in the output window... Damn. I'm stuck here..

Comment: Found it!! this works: Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource VisibleConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}, AncestorLevel=1},Path=IsSelected}" Thx for your help and guidance in the right direction :)

Answer (score 2):

It should work when you bind the `IsSelected` property of the `ListBoxItem` to your property `IsVisible`. But it depends on how you have implemented your ViewModel and the properties.

```
<ListBox>
  <!-- the rest of the XAML-Definition of your ListBox -->
  <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
      <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsVisible, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </Style>
  </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand me, or I you :) I need the tick image only to be visible when I select an item in the listbox. If the item is not selected the tick image should not be visible. Only the 4 selected items in the example image (see start post) should have the tick mark. Where would you add your xaml in my xaml?

Comment: @PitAttack76 add the Xaml to the rest of your xaml. You need no converter to make it work.